# Pub.dev requires dart formatting with line length = 80?

Tags: dart

I just published a package on `pub.dev` and my score was 120/130 with this in the report:

[image]

When I run `flutter format . -line-length=120`, no changes are made to my code (thanks to the setting that runs `dart format` on save). When I run `flutter format .` (with the default line length of 80) I get lots of changes. Thing is, I don't want my line length to be 80.

Is 80 characters a recommendation for packages on `pub.dev`?

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dev/issues/3041

Comment: @julemand101 thanks. It occurs to me that I can use a line width of 120 in my repo and just run `flutter format .` before running `dart pub publish` and not push the formatted files to the repo, so keep 120 in my repo.